# Issue loading jQuery in Webpacker 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm trying to add jQuery as a Webpacker/Webpack (5.4.3) plugin to my Rails (6.0.4.1) app, but I keep getting a "jQuery is not defined error." I'm using the following code, which seems to be the general answer to this question on most searches:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Now, I CAN get it working using the following code:

```
// application.js

import $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.js';

globalThis.jQuery = $;
globalThis.$ = $;
```

I'm fairly new to Webpack/Webpacker, so I'm mostly just trying to understand why the top solution won't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The provider module automatically loads the module, **but**, it is made available only within the files that are actually **ES Modules**. ES Module is a JS file containing at least one `import` or `export` statement or a file ending with `.mjs` extension.

```
environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
);
```

The above code will make **identifiers** `$` and `jQuery` available within any **ES Module** whenever Webpack encounters these free identifiers in your code. **In other words, the `ProvidePlugin` doesn't really modify the global scope**.

Inside your `application.js` file, you will need to do what you have done:

```
globalThis.jQuery = $;

// or
window.jQuery = $;
```

And your `application.js` file should have at least one `import` or `export` statement not necessarily the **jQuery** import statement. Alternately, if you do not like it then, you can also consider using [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader).